# Custom views and window attributes on Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, view

What I want to do is add a view on top of my application which will be sort of a filter view (I want to manipulate the colors of the screen) and I also want to be able to change the brightness of the screen at the same time. Both of these things seem to work separately, but not together.

**Here is my code:**

Adding view:

```
colourView = new Layer(cordova.getActivity());

WindowManager localWindowManager = (WindowManager) cordova.getActivity().getWindowManager();
LayoutParams layoutParams = cordova.getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;

layoutParams.type=LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
layoutParams.flags=LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
layoutParams.gravity=Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP; 

localWindowManager.addView(colourView, layoutParams);
```

Layer class:

```
class Layer extends View
{
      private int a = 0;
      private int b = 0;
      private int g = 0;
      private int r = 0;

      public Layer(Context context){
        super(context);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawARGB(this.a, this.r, this.g, this.b);
        Log.d("display", "rendering..");
      }

      @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth / 2, parentHeight);
            //Since you are attatching it to the window use window layout params.
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(parentWidth / 2,
                    parentHeight);
            this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            Log.d("display", "filling...");
        }

      public void setColor(int a, int r, int g, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
        invalidate();
       }
}
```

Changing brightness:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = cordova.getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
try {
    layout.screenBrightness = (float) arg_object.getDouble("brightness");
    // ^ When I comment this line, it doesn't work either.
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
cordova.getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
```

When I add the view to the application and, after that, I want to change brightness of the screen - brightness is changing, but I can't click on anything on the screen. After few second I get an 'Application not responding message.

**What causes my application to freeze?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = cordova.getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
```

In this line you getting the `Layoutparams` object of the `Activity`. This is only a reference to the `LayoutParams` object in the `Activity`.

Now you are changing this object:

```
layoutParams.type=LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
layoutParams.flags=LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |     LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
layoutParams.gravity=Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.TOP;
```

wehereby you are changing the attributes of the `Activity` and amongst other things, setting the `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag for the **`Activity`**, causing it to appear not responding, because it has been made not focusable.

Changing this line

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = cordova.getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
```

to

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams();
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I got one more problem: When I click 'Home button', exception is thrown: Activity has leaked window... from this line:     localWindowManager.addView(colourView, layoutParams);. Do you know what can cause it?

Comment: Please create a separate question.